# How can the SVN version or build timestamp be added to the Maven package result?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I have maven project that consists of several modules.
I want to add an SVN version information to every module being built e.g.
assuming that the structure is as follows:

parent-proj
     --moduleA
     --moduleB

I want that the moduleA and moduleB package phase would add the SVN info to the moduleA and moduleB build results: for example moduleA-.jar.

Thanks,

Aviad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [build number maven plugin.](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: How do we get both the SVN verion and build number?

Comment: ${scmBranch} and ${buildNumber} are available to use in your POM file. You can use the Maven Replacer Plugin to rename/move files with this value if you like.